# Checking for NaN bit patterns in C++

Tags: c++, floating-point, c++20

I live in hostile environments (GCC and Clang) which remove calls to `isnan` which prevents me to perform validation of my input before running computations.

Here is a potential replacement: is this a correct implementation of `isnan` (no matter whether the NaN is quiet or signaling - I am reading random data from untrusted sources and have to filter anything that is not a real number) ?

```
constexpr bool safe_isnan(double val) noexcept
{
  const auto x = std::bit_cast<uint64_t>(val);

  return (x >= 0x7FF0000000000001ull && x <= 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFull)
      || (x >= 0xFFF0000000000001ull)
  ;
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132412/discussion-on-question-by-jean-michael-celerier-checking-for-nan-bit-patterns-in).

Answer (score 13):

First of all, the compiler is not hostile; by using `-ffast-math` you are asking for an optimization that the compiler dutifully performs. Perhaps it is not what you desired the compiler would do in this particular case, but please don't attribute that to maliciousness from the compiler or the compiler developers.

Compilers routinely are able to look at code patterns and see that a piece of code does the same as some built-in function, and replace one with the other, and then perform more optimizations on it. So in theory, the compiler might decide that what you are doing is the same as `std::isnan()`. Luckily, current versions of GCC and Clang don't optimize your `safe_isnan()` away.

Also be aware that as part of `-ffast-math` optimizations, an operation that would have resulted in a NaN might now return a finite value. `safe_isnan()` is not going to protect you against that. So it might work for values you read directly from disk or network, but be aware of this when using it on the results of arithmetic operations.

Answer (score 7):

You have missed the namespace qualifier of `std::uint64_t`.  <del>It seems that `std::uint_fast64_t` should be sufficient, to make the code more portable.</del>  The exact-width type is probably appropriate, but we should confirm that using `static_assert(sizeof (double) == sizeof (std::uint64_t)`.

We probably want to ensure that the types have the same endianness - probably the easiest way to do that is follow the definition with a compile-time test like

```
static_assert(safe_isnan(std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN()));
```

It looks like the test could be simplified.  Instead of those `>=` and `<=` comparisons, just check the relevant bits are set:

```
auto constexpr ones_mask = 0x7ff0000000000000;
auto constexpr zero_mask = 0x000fffffffffffff;

return (x & ones_mask) == ones_mask  &&  (x & zero_mask) != 0;
```

We should probably conditionalise on `std::numeric_limits<double>::is_iec559` since we depend on the floating-point layout.

The whole thing should be unnecessary - but if you've you've selected `-ffast-math`, then your compiler can assume that these bit patterns are impossible.  You probably need to compile this function separately without that option for it to work reliably.  But in that case, you might as well just compile a tiny (non-fastmath) wrapper that ensures the standard `isnan()` is called:

```
bool safe_isnan(double val) noexcept { return std::isnan(val); }
```

(Note: not `constexpr`, and take steps to avoid inlining - or link-time optimisation)

Another alternative is to use (or reimplement) `std::fpclassify()` and use that to implement your versions of `isnan()`, `isfinite()`, etc.

Comment: Oops yes - and that `double` is the expected size.  I was going to suggest a `static_assert()` but forgot.

Comment: Is `std::uint_fast64_t` really a better choice, though?  It could be wider than `double`, which would break `std::bit_cast`.  Since these constants are designed for IEEE754 binary64, it's fine (and maybe better) to require an integer type that's exactly 64-bit.

Comment: Something like `(x | 0x8000000000000000ull) > 0xfff0000000000000ull` might be even more efficient.

Comment: Absolutely right @Peter - updated.

Comment: @Ilmari: perhaps, but I'd want to measure.  There's more scope for instruction reordering and fine-grained parallel computation in my version, so it could go either way.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: or `x<<1` to discard the sign bit instead of forcing it to 1.  Good idea, on many ISAs that would avoid needing another 64-bit constant.  (x86-64 has `bts` that can set a single bit, but on x86-64 ANDing with `ones_mask` would require a 10-byte `mov r64, imm64` / 3-byte `and r64, r64`.  AArch64 bit-range immediates let it AND or OR in one instruction, but just as easily shift.)  Right-shifting to the bottom would allow an easy AND or OR immediate and an immediate compare.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen's suggestion does compile the best for ARM64 and x86-64, especially with x86-64 gcc.  https://godbolt.org/z/bcz84a1v3  Toby's version compiles with a branch instead of cmov for the original from the question.  Also included a version of my right-shift idea, returning an integer 0 / non-zero that the caller can test/branch on without materializing a boolean 0 / 1.  We can just return `x << 12` (i.e. the mantissa bits) if the exponent is all-ones, otherwise return 0. That avoids large constants, but the code-size ends up worse than Ilmari's I think.  (Especially Ilmari's w. `x<<1`

Comment: Of course the best asm would be an FP compare -> setcc, instead of trying to trick the compiler, if you're using a separate file.  (But having a non-inline `call` inside an FP loop can suck a lot, because x86-64 System V has no call-preserved XMM registers among other things.)  I don't think gcc/clang will look for integer stuff that's guaranteed false by non-NaN, because they'd have to specifically look for that, and recognize an idiom or something, but that's not an optimization normal people want.

Comment: One may want, if there's no way to prevent inlining/LTO/etc., to write the value into a `volatile` and then read it back. Then the compiler won't be able to make assumptions on the value read back, and won't optimize away the custom check for NaN.

Comment: @Ruslan, have you confirmed that with many compilers?  If that's reliable, it's a very good suggestion.

Comment: I've used it for such a purpose in GCC mainly (including with all optimizations turned on), but according to the Standard, it should work in any compliant compiler, see [intro.execution/8.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/intro.execution#8.1), [intro.execution/12](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/intro.execution#12), also GCC docs on [When is a Volatile Object Accessed?](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Volatiles.html#Volatiles), [When is a Volatile C++ Object Accessed?](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Volatiles.html).

Comment: @Ruslan: Interesting idea, but not helpful for making `isnan()` work.  GCC/clang `-ffast-math` assume that a `double` read from a `volatile` is finite (https://godbolt.org/z/Y36f8YP59 shows store/reload but unconditional return 0), just like a buffer filled by a non-inline function, and thus optimize away `isnan`.  I thought `-fno-builtin-isnan` might help as a costly alternative, but no.  If you meant to make this answer work super safely, by laundering the `uint64_t` that holds a double bit-pattern, that's not actually needed with current optimizers, and unlikely compilers would look for it.

Comment: @PeterCordes oh well, then the safest way to get it to work is to actually remove assumptions that the values are always finite: use `-ffast-math -fno-finite-math-only`. This will retain other optimization options enabled by `-ffast-math`, but no longer assume that values are finite. (Your Godbolt examples get fixed by this.) This way may have some slowdown effect, but should be still better than with `-fno-fast-math`.

Comment: @Ruslan: The best bet is to compile a separate `.cpp` with appropriate optimization options, with a wrapper function for `isnan`.  The querent said in chat under the question that they have some weird build setup that enforces LTO or whole-program optimization, making it inconvenient to build one file differently.  They'd have to check whether they could use `-fno-finite-math-only` without losing the major speedups they get from fast-math.  (If it's mostly auto-vectorization, a lot of that's still possible with inf / nan being possible, as long as -fno-trapping-math is on.)

Answer (score 0):

**Minor: `ll` serves no purpose here**

[DRYer code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)
`ll` is useful to force a minimum width type.  Unnecessary with all same sign type compares.

```
const auto x = std::bit_cast<uint64_t>(val);

// return (x >= 0x7FF0000000000001ull && x <= 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFull)
//     || (x >= 0xFFF0000000000001ull);
return (x >= 0x7FF0000000000001u && x <= 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFu)
    || (x >= 0xFFF0000000000001u);
```

... or re-formed as

```
return (x & 7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFu) >= 0x7FF0000000000001u;
```